# About node controller

Tags: cloud, maas

I have installed MAAS , but i am having difficulty in installing node . In the documentation i am having difficulty in how to configure each node for wake on lan and pxe .. how to select pxe boot to first ..

Also To use ISC, your /etc/cobbler/modules.conf should contain , where i should write and how i should write this command in my node . When i configure for node in the installation i Select Select Maas by name or address , after that i put the ip address of my MAAS server but after it it automatically closes .

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look in your hardware's manual or search the web to get it configured for WoL and PXE; it's fairly vendor-specific.

Unfortunately I don't understand the second part of your question. Could you try rephrasing it, or adding some details? What are you trying to do? What did you expect to happen?